# Empty picture on checkout stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have implemented the stripe checkout using node.js

`product.photo` is `https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/2213131`

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
  line_items: [{
    name: product.title,
    description: product.description,
    images: [product.photo],
    amount: product.price * 100,
    currency: "usd",
    quantity: 1
  }],
  success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
  cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
});
```

For some reason, the picture is always empty

> [image]

Other data is fine

Comment: Can you view the image in the browser when you visit the url directly ?
I get a "AccessDenied" error

Comment: How does `product.photo` looks like? Does request for the image returns anything / emty data / 404 ...? What actually downloads the data - server or client?

Comment: Yeah I can access https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/2213131 but for some reason when passing to the create-session it shows 404 .

Comment: What does your browser console says ?

Comment: The photo is not publicly available, make it public in S3.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande The link is for example, I could download it

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande the console says GET https://stripe-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/10127f90cbc066bb296072d3e3fb11e5e520bbb1/68747470733a2f2f6c6561726e70616c2d61646d696e2e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f31353734393637393732393239 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you download it from incognito? Or in another device? You may be authenticated.

Comment: Yeah it is possible. to download it from incognito or a different device @MarcosCasagrande . Should I use cloudfront?

Comment: @airsoftFreak Hey, I'm getting the same problem - did you manage to fix it?

Comment: For anyone finding this: Turns out Stripe don't like .jfif files, added a jpg instead and it worked

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [Sumit Datta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148142/sumit-datta), it was the content-type metadata on S3 that was causing this issue. Make sure you use `image/jpeg` or `image/png` as the content-type, else Stripe's CDN won't be able to cache your images!

Comment: hoke
how to customize title on checkout pls? just like this in this screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCOA5qHUu4QTl8xMUxEiEt2jjir7ab3U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Please make sure to use the correct "content-type" for your images when storing to S3. That should fix it. Check that your browser does not download image as attachment, rather shows image in browser.

Answer (score 0):

[https://domain/ + product.img] important not http

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35062339)